# parameter passed to relationship from controller to model in laravel but not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, parameters, relationship

in my controller parameter passed to posts function in user model with construct method .

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    private $user;
    public function __construct(User $getuser)
    {
        $this->user = $getuser;
    }
    public function index($id = 2)
    {
        $posts = $this->user->posts($id);
        $user = User::FindOrFail($id);
        return $user->posts;
    }
}
```

in my user model parameter accessed and passed to relationship .

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    function posts($id)
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->where('id',$id);
    }
}
```

it works when use like this

> "return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->where('id',1);"

but not working with passed parameter. getting this error

> "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Too few
> arguments to function App\User::posts(), 0 passed in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php
> on line 415 and exactly 1 expected"

Comment: return $user->posts($id)

Answer (score 1):

Check your controller method you should be returning. ie: `return $posts` instead of `return $user->posts` as this is seeking to find posts without passing in the id as you do with `$posts = $this->user->posts($id);`

That's why you are getting a symphony error of too few arguments as you pass no arguments in `return $user->posts`

Answer (score 0):

User Model

```
function posts($id)
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

You could access the post with the given condition by using where on the relation method.

**Querying relations**
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

```
$post = $user->posts()->where('id', $id)->first();

You could use get() or first() according to your requirement.

$posts = $user->posts()->where('id', $id)->get();
```

If you want a user who has a post that satisfies the criteria.

```
$user = User::whereHas('posts', function($query) use($id){
         $query->where('id', $id);
         // You may add several other conditions as well.
      })
      ->with(['posts' => function($query) use($id){
           $query->where('id', $id);
         }
      ])
      ->first();
```

Now,

```
$user->posts

will give a collection of only ONE post Model Instance that satisfied the condition
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, can you please explain? Also the above way solves your purpose and I think it is better if you do that way, because in case you want to access all the posts at some place, it could get you that too and for getting a single post you could always query the relation.

Comment: i want the users that have posts and posts should be according to the parameter.
like this
$user = User::whereHas('posts')->find($id);
        return $user;

Comment: You could do that by keeping the same relation as I said. And it gives you even more freedom because it would not be simply constrained to use one id, you can add multiple conditions as much as you want. I'll write an example in the solution. And then let me know if that is what you need.